# Spotfire - Add customised header to report table

Tags: report, reporting, spotfire, tibco

I have columns in table as:

Year, Case, Area, Gross Value 1, Gross Value 2 Gross Profit, Net Value 1, Net Value 2, Net Production

I want to add an additional header row to report as shown below. Not looking for cross table but just additional row for header.

```
                   |        GROSS             |      NET
Year | Case | Area | Value1 | Value2  | profit| Value1 | Value2 | Production
```

If this achievable in Spotfire report ?

Comment: What do you mean another header row to a report? What "report"?

Comment: This is from data table(columns in information link) to report (display table).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible natively in Spotfire. You will have to build and populate a report in the Text Area to achieve this, using JS, IronPy, and HTML (any combination of the three).

[Here's an idea for the headers](https://betterinfosec.com/2013/10/28/using-custom-html-in-spotfire/).